# Symfony controller not redirecting

Tags: php, symfony

I have this in controller

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('success_template'));

return 'other template stuff...'
```

routing.yml

```
success_template:
    path: /success
    defaults:
        _controller:  FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:     'MyDefaultBundle:Default:success.html.twig'
```

Everytime i go to home page my nomral template appears instead of redirecting to success template which is simple hello world template

Answer (score 6):

You have to `return` (the response for redirect):

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('success_template'));
```